# GNUPLOT remove overlapping between xtick labels

Tags: gnuplot

In **GnuPlot**, i am setting **xtics** to something like this:

> set xtics
>   ("AIM" 0.00000, "gtalk" 2.00000, "rtp-multicast-filetransfer" 4.00000,
>   "sipc_music" 6.00000, "skype1" 8.00000, "skype2" 10.00000,
>   "voip-extension" 12.00000, "voip-extension2downata" 14.00000,
>   "ymessenger" 16.00000)

The problem is, that these labels overlap with each other in the plot, so how can i remove/overcome this overlapping?

Can I increase the length between **xticks** or write some kind of legend showing:
`rmf : rtp-multicast-filetransfer` ?

Answer (score 7):

This might not be the solution you want, but you can rotate labels with:

`set xtics rotate by -45`

This would rotate tick labels at the x-axis by -45°.

Comment: Do you know of any way to centre the label about the xtic, instead of label starting from the xtick?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, but wouldn't that look strange? I imagine if they don't start at the tick, the reader could be confused where the labels belong to.

Comment: true.. the problem with rotating it is that the label for the last xtic gets truncated by the border.

Comment: Maybe depends on the output - seems to work here: http://img.xrmb2.net/images/534339.png - I hope someone more familiar with GNUPlot can be of more help. ;-)